# PowerShell Form Resize Event

Tags: forms, winforms, powershell, resize

I need to dynamically resize a form object when the form resizes. The user will drag and drop the edge of the form to resize it. I've been searching for the correct syntax to manage a form resize event in PowerShell, but have been unsuccessful.

Could someone tell me why `resizeEnd` doesn't work on the form? Also, what the correct syntax would be to handle the resize event?

This is what I was attempting, but I kept getting errors:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1066,518)
$form.KeyPreview = $true
$form.StartPosition = "centerscreen"
$form.BackColor = "MidnightBlue"

$form.Add_KeyDown({
    if($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") {
        $form.Close()
    }
})

$form.Text = "Dialog Box 5.1" 
$form.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + "\powershell_ise.exe")
$form.MinimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1066,525)

#$form.SizeChanged({ $errorBox1.AppendText("resize") })
#$form.Resize({ Write-Host "resize" })
#$form.ClientSizeChanged({ Write-Host "size" })
$form.ResizeEnd({ Write-Host "resize" })
#$form.SizeChanged({ Write-Host "size" })
#$form.ControlAdded({ Write-Host "event" })
#$form.AutoSizeMode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode
#$form.AutoSizeMode = "GrowAndShrink"
#$form.OnDragDrop({ Write-Host "drop" })

$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Basically, I was trying to say, "If the form is resized write-host that the form was resized".

Comment: Here's a [link](https://foxdeploy.com/series/learning-gui-toolmaking-series/) to (IMO) better GUI creation with PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but besides a basic course in GUI I don't see how it is relevant to this question at all. I've looked through the sub links about .Net on the page and it doesn't talk about resize event handlers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example:

```
$form.Add_Resize({
    "form resized"
})
```

or

```
$resizeHandler = { "form resized" }

$form.Add_Resize( $resizeHandler )
```

[Some documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize(v=vs.110).aspx)

Try this to see a long list of methods exposed by `System.Windows.Forms.Form`:

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$form | Get-Member -Force
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. I love the additional assistance in showing us where to go for additional dev work.